# I am new to django, I tried registration of users but there is a error while I try to go to the page

Tags: python, django

**Traceback:**

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /collaborative/
Exception Value: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from . import views 
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^$', views.UserFormView.as_view, name='register'), ]
```

**views.py**

class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'collaborative/registration_form.html'

```
def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request,self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

# Process the form data 
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

```
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)

       /* cleaned and  normalized data */
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        # returns user objects if credentials are correct

        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                request.redirect('collborative:profile')

    return render(request,self.template_name, {'form' : form})
```

Comment: Please share urls.py and views.py code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, it was a missing bracket

from django.conf.urls import url 
from . import views 
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'), ]